# Rest, ngresource, $resource not returning anything

Tags: rest, angularjs

I'm trying to GET Rest data from a parse.com backend with Angularjs. I expect at least console log you can see in the code below to return something, but it returns nothing, and there are no error in the console.

Here is the code i'm trying:
Full Javascript code:

```
var todoApp = angular.module('todoApp', ['ngResource']);


todoApp.factory('todoFactory', function($resource) {
    return $resource('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Professional', {}, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'X-Parse-Application-Id':'xxx', 'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'yyy'}
    });
});

function TodoController($scope, $location, todoFactory) {
    function loadTodos() {
        $scope.items = todoFactory.query();
        console.log(todoFactory.query());  //i expect this to log something at least
    }

}
```

Full html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="TodoController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items"> {{item.firstName}} </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

Any clue on how to give life to this dead code ?

Comment: Do you actually call the `loadTodos` function in your controller?

Comment: Yes, when I call it with for example:     <button type="button" ng-click="loadTodos()">Get Items</button>
still nothing happens.

Comment: This way will not work, because your function isn't defined at `$scope`. Try change the function to `$scope.loadTodos = function() { /* ... */} `.

Comment: Can you please show this in context ? I didn't see this kind of way of doing in the docs i've read but I guess you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not calling your function.

You have two options:

In your controller:

```
function TodoController($scope, $location, todoFactory) {
    function loadTodos() {
        $scope.items = todoFactory.query();
        console.log(todoFactory.query()); 
    }
    // You declare the function, now you can use this
    loadTodos();
}
```

But, in this way, the function isn't available in your view, because it isn't declared in the `$scope`. To that, you should declare like this:

```
function TodoController($scope, $location, todoFactory) {
    $scope.loadTodos = function() {
        $scope.items = todoFactory.query();
        console.log(todoFactory.query()); 
    }
}
```

You declare the function in $scope, now you can use in the view like this:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="loadTodos()">Get Items</button>
```

Comment: I got it thanks a lot. I had issues with headers not correctly being sent as in my example above, but I managed to fix it.